# Can we automatically refresh spring properties file without using actuator refresh endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, configserver

I am trying to implement spring cloud I want to refresh my .properties as soon as I make changes to it without hitting the actuator refresh end point.Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please describe the problem in more detail? What versions? Where is your .properties files stored?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.